# Executing batch file within another batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I must be wrong with my syntax here, but what I want to do is basically run a starting batch file that will allow me to pass in all the file names in a directory that are .txt files into another batch file where the external batch file will print out the file names to the user. I'm also running in MS-DOS if that matters at all.

This is what I have so far:

STRT.BAT

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%P IN (*.TXT) DO EXTERNAL "%%P"
```

EXTERNAL.BAT

```
@ECHO OFF
PRINT "%~1"
```

For some reason I'm getting a syntax error when I run my start.bat

Comment: "*I'm also running in MS-DOS*" - no you are not. MS-DOS has been extinct for decades now. You probably mean the command line in Windows

Comment: No I was actually running MS-DOS in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the external.bat to return control you have to do

```
for %%P in (*.TXT) do call external.bat %%P
```

(You may have the number of percents wrong. Its been a while.)

Comment: Your call command helped but now I'm getting a 'File not found - %P' for each text file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around %%P so `external "%%P"`. This means external gets it with quotes so can read into `%1`.

In External it is %1 not %%P. So `type "%~1"`. Plus you need quotes so type can find the file (tilde removes quotes so you start with a string in a known format).

Call isn't needed in this situation, `for` is calling external.bat not your bat directly.

Your batch works here with the changes I said. But you won't post your code.

```
C:\Users\David Candy>a

C:\Users\David Candy>FOR %P IN (*.bat) DO B "%P"

C:\Users\David Candy>B "cmdline.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "cmdline.bat"
echo %~dpnx0

C:\Users\David Candy>B "delstack.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "delstack.bat"
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*gravatar*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*stackoverflow*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*adzerk*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*stack*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*google-analytics*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*quantserve*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*scorecardresearch*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*adzerk*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*facebook*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*sstatic*.*" /s
del "%userprofile%\appdata\*static*.*" /s


C:\Users\David Candy>B "nytdelete.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "nytdelete.bat"
del "C:\Users\David Candy\AppData\*nytimes*.*" /s

C:\Users\David Candy>B "sdk.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "sdk.bat"
cd /d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Include

C:\Users\David Candy>B "sdksearch.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "sdksearch.bat"
cd /d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Include
 *.hstr /i /c:"0xD0000022"

C:\Users\David Candy>B "SearchReplace.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "SearchReplace.bat"
@echo off &setlocal
set search=%1
set replace=%2
set Textfile=Input.txt
set newfile=Input.txt
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%

C:\Users\David Candy>B "sysdir.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "sysdir.bat"
cd /d c:\windows\system32

C:\Users\David Candy>B "windir.bat"

C:\Users\David Candy>TYPE "windir.bat"
cd /d c:\windows

C:\Users\David Candy>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to output the file names but they come up as "Parameter format not correct - "TEXT.TXT"

Comment: Still getting the same issue as I mentioned. Getting parameter format not correct.

Comment: I took some screenshots. I need to have the call command. Otherwise, it's only picking up the first text file. http://imgur.com/a/mG7Oc

Comment: When I add in the tilde, all that outputs is 'Parameter format not correct - "%1~" '

Comment: it types all files here withoutthe useof call. I suspect when your command is correct call isn't needeed.

Comment: the ~ is before the number not after it.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I put the tilde in the correct spot and removed the call like you said. This is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/tot60eK.png

Comment: You can't call your command start. Type `start /?` to see why. And anymore problems you must post code.

Comment: That didn't really solve anything. Still the same issues after changing to a new batch file. I've updated the post with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%P IN (*.TXT) DO call EXTERNAL "%%P"
```

or

```dos
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%P IN (*.TXT) DO start "" EXTERNAL "%%P"
```

The first will execute the process `external` serially, waiting for `external` to finish with one before proceeding to the next. The second wil attempt to run all in parallel.

The issues are the requirements of the built-in "start" command - the first quoted string is used as a window title, so you need to feed it a dummy title, and you can't use start.bat as a filename since `start` is inbuilt.

If your `external.bat` s as simple as you indicate, then why not just use

```dos
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%P IN (*.TXT) DO Print "%%P"
```

(oversimplification often masks other problems)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers I was given were over complicated. I managed to figure it out:

EXCHANGE.BAT

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %1
```

STRT.BAT

```
FOR %%P IN (*.TXT) DO CALL EXTERNAL %%P
```